# Discover Microsoft SQL Servers on an Internal Network

Tags: .net, sql-server, wmi

What is the proper way using .NET to discover the Microsoft SQL Servers on your internal network? I think the SQL Management interface back in the SQL Server 7 days gave you a list of servers in a dropdown. How could I do the same thing with .NET 3.5.